# SQL query to get max value record in last 5 or 10 day

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose there is a table- Restaurant

```
id  |  order | date_time | bill(Rs.)
[1]  [Fish] [2018-06-17 17:06:28]  [2000]
[2]  [Meat] [2018-06-16 18:08:28]  [3000]
[3]  [Rice] [2018-05-22 21:09:28]  [4000]
```

Now I want the highest Bill Paid in last 5 day. What query should I use?

The answer should be 3000 not 4000.
Please help me out.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: WHERE plus LIMIT 1

Comment: What happens if you get a draw?

Comment: Question is a little unclear are you asking for the max bill or the whole row with the max bill?

Comment: Are you going to get bills with dates in the future? If not, all the answers so far are over-complicating the test.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from Restaurant 
where bill = (select MAX(bill) from Restaurant 
where date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW() );
```

Comment: An explanation why you would do it like this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are calculating five days before current date

```
   SELECT MAX(bill) FROM restaurant_table 
   WHERE DATE_TIME  BETWEEN 
   DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
   AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want previous five days data from current date

```
 SELECT MAX(BIL) FROM resturant
  WHERE     DATE_TIME  
 BETWEEN  
 DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND 
 NOW();
```

Comment: Why have you posted 2 answers (both the same)?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,order,date_time,max(sum(bill)) as paid_bill from restaurant
   where date_time between (NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) and  NOW()
   group by order;
```

i hope it will work.

- in where clause date_time need two date to filter 5 days data
- then group all data and sum them
- which one maximum this is your max bill paid order